# How is this piezoelectric effect converted to voltage?

Tags: sensor

The data-sheet of [this](https://www.bksv.com/media/doc/Bp2035.pdf) accelerometer says:

> This piezoelectric accelerometer may be treated as a charge source.
>   Its sensitivity is expressed in terms of charge per unit acceleration
>   (pC/ms–2, pC/g).

Is it possible to convert this pC/g to V/g? How is it converted to voltage so that it is amplified?

Comment: It will also have a (specified or measurable) capacitance. Any circuit you connect to it will have additional capacitance.

Comment: What is unclear about "Any circuit you connect to it will have additional capacitance."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way this is done is by measuring the flow of charge (current) from the device into an inverting amplifier circuit: -

[image]

[Analog Devices app note CN0350](http://www.analog.com/en/design-center/reference-designs/hardware-reference-design/circuits-from-the-lab/cn0350.html#rd-functionbenefits) is where this circuit came from and here is a brief extract from that page: -

> Piezoelectric elements are commonly used for the measurement of
>   acceleration and vibration. Here, the piezoelectric crystal is used in
>   conjunction with a seismic mass m. If the mass is subjected to an
>   acceleration a, then there is a resulting inertial force F = m × a
>   acting on the seismic mass and the piezoelectric crystal. This results
>   in the crystal acquiring a charge q = d × F, where d (measured in
>   coulombs/newton, C/N) is the crystal charge sensitivity to force.
>
> The resulting steady-state charge sensitivity Sa of piezoelectric
>   accelerometer is Sa = Δq/Δa (measured in C × s2/m).
>
> Note that acceleration can be converted to g using the relationship 1
>   g = 9.81 m/s2.

Comment: Thanks. In the software where you can update the settings(such as filters amplification) there is also a section called cable length. And default it is set to zero. So does it also have to be updated since the cable adds to the total capacitance seen by the amplifier?

Comment: What software do you refer to?

Comment: This accerlerometer https://www.bksv.com/media/doc/Bp2035.pdf has a software where one can set filters and output gain ect. There is also a part that you fill in the cable length I always keep it zero. I was wondering whether the cable length goes to equations as capacitance.  See in this manual https://www.bksv.com/media/doc/bp1853.pdf Figure 4. at page 4.  Under transducer setup one of the adjustable parameter is "cable length". I dont know why they mention it and how much would it matter.